# javascript how to calculate values in dynamically added fields with multiple rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-arithmetic

I had one row with three fields: `received, issue, balance`

```
<input type="text" name="rcv" class="rcv"/>
<input type="text" name="issue" class="issue"/>
<input type="text" name="blnc" class="balance"/>
```

I calculated the balance for each row easily, but how do I calculate more than one row?

Each row has `receive`, `issue` and `balance` fields.

How do I calculate each row's balance field?

I tried like this for multiple row but it's not working:

```
    $('.t_rtn, .t_rcv').each(function(){
    $(this).on('blur',function(){
      var totalRcv = $('.t_rcv').val();
      var totalRtn = $('.t_rtn').val();
      // console.log( $('t_rtn').next('.consume').val() );
      $('t_rtn').next('.consume').val(totalRcv-totalRtn);
    });
```

Comment: Protip: you're subtracting strings. Input `values` are returned as a string, so you need to convert it to avoid pesky `NaN` issues.

Comment: You also need to use the correct selectors. Your elements have class `rcv` and `issue` but your selectors are adding a `t_` prefix.

Comment: In addition to lack of casting and the wrong selectors, the other problem is that you were grabbing multiple elements possibly since you were selecting from document level parent. If you select from row level parent you will only grab the values from that row.. see my example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to parsing the string values into integers you also need to use the correct selectors for those input elements. `t_rtn` is not the right class name, for example. And if doing this in rows you will want to grab the correct element from the current row (you already did this correctly for the consume field)

Fixed html (Example.. I chose to use `div` with class name = `row`):

```
<div class='row'>
<input type="text" name="rcv" class="receive"/>
<input type="text" name="issue" class="return"/>
<input type="text" name="blnc" class="balance"/>
</div>
<div class='row'>
<input type="text" name="rcv" class="receive"/>
<input type="text" name="issue" class="return"/>
<input type="text" name="blnc" class="balance"/>
</div>
<div class='row'>
<input type="text" name="rcv" class="receive"/>
<input type="text" name="issue" class="return"/>
<input type="text" name="blnc" class="balance"/>
</div>
```

Fixed code:

```
 $(document).on('blur','.receive, .return', function()
 {
    var $row = $(this).closest(".row");
    var totalRcv = parseInt($row.find('.receive').val()) || 0;
    var totalRtn = parseInt($row.find('.return').val()) || 0;
    $row.find('.balance').val(totalRcv - totalRtn);
 });
```

I took the liberty of fixing some inconsistencies with the class names used. I tried to match them up to the variables for `totalRcv` and `totalRtn` so that now the `balance` shows as receipt minus return. If the user enters non-numeric data, it defaults the value to 0 before calculating.

Example fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cp81g4nf/1/

Comment: No problem, I was just doing this recently myself.

Answer (score 1):

you need to parse The value of textbox as it returns string not int

```
 $('.t_rtn, .t_rcv').each(function(){
    $(this).on('blur',function(){
      var totalRcv = parseInt($('.t_rcv').val()) || 0;
      var totalRtn = parseInt($('.t_rtn').val()) || 0;
      // console.log( $('t_rtn').next('.consume').val() );
      $('t_rtn').next('.consume').val(totalRcv-totalRtn);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If your code is being run on document.ready it will only be applied to elements which exist  at that point.

You'd be better with :

```
$(document).on('blur','.t_rtn, .t_rcv',function(){
  var val = $(this).val();

  ...
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
 $(document).on('blur','.receive, .return', function()
 {
    var $row = $(this).closest(".row");
    var totalRcv = parseInt($row.find('.receive').val()) || 0;
    var totalRtn = parseInt($row.find('.return').val()) || 0;
    $row.find('.balance').val(totalRcv - totalRtn);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is because you are subtracting 2 Strings. `.val` returns an String.

Convert them in number before subtracting like bellow

```
$('t_rtn').next('.consume').val((+totalRcv)-(+totalRtn));
```